# Implicit function theorem for polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, implicit-function-theorem

I am looking at this version of the implicit function theorem [image: this version]   (taken from Krantz, "Function theory of several complex variables").

If I assume that every $f_j$ is algebraic function (or at least a polynomial), is it fair to say that the solution $w(z)$ is also an algebraic function? To me it seems that it should almost follow from the definition of the algebraic function (i.e., it's a root of a polynomial equation).

But then when I look at the algebraic version of the theorem form Kendig "Elementary algebraic geometry"
[image]
then it again says that the solution is analytic.

So is it possible that such a solution would *not* be algebraic?

Comment: Perhaps part of the point is that an algebraic function isn't actually a function -- it's multivalued. So saying there's an analytic function in a neighborhood is saying that locally you can choose a branch to make it an honest analytic function

Comment: Thank you @KevinCasto! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You are right: algebraic functions are analytic, and the implicit function defined by algebraic equations is algebraic, by definition, and there is no contradiction in the texts you cite.